# Why does golang seem to disappear?

Tags: linux, go, installation

Golang seems to disappear on me, I'll close all of my prompts and it basically deletes it. So I go back in and do # ./installer_linux and the following thing that pops up, but after I close all the prompts and wait say 20 or 300 min it shows golang doesn't exist! Did I install wrong? Do I have a setting that is messing with it?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you aren't adding Go to your path.  But the fact that you have a `./installer_linux` is odd to begin with.  This is how I normally install Go:

```
cd ~
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.14.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Then, assuming you are using a bash shell, you need to add the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

to one of the following files (try them one by one or just add it to all of them):

- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.profile

If you are using zsh, you would add it to ~/.zshrc

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8bV2.png      Here is a picture of my .profile I'm having trouble on where to put the export?

Comment: Omg thanks it was the the 2 .bash Idk which one but exporting there worked, thank you! :)